# How to batch edit the background of photos?

Tags: software-recommendation, photo-editing, background-removal

I have a fairly large number of images of peoples faces that all have slightly different back drops. 
I want to standardise these backgrounds to a block colour (blue/white/green).

I was wondering how I can do this and with which application or website (preferably free, and whether it can be done as one batch?

Answer (score 1):

Cutting background of a person is one of the most difficult things to do. Every case is diferent.

Normally the process is backwards. If you shoot on a green, blue or white screen it is easier to do something faster. But even in this case you need to adjust the settings case by case.

A blond woman, burnette, highlights, exposition, uniformity of the background ilumination.

So. In short. **You can not batch that**.

Free? Gimp.  https://www.google.com/?client=firefox-b-ab#q=Gimp+extract+hair

P.S. When you cut the hair, please, do not assign any color, leave the image masked and assign the background in another layer.

Answer (score 0):

**Software:**
Gimp or [Pixlr for web](https://pixlr.com/editor/) would be some free Photoshop alternatives. You can also get a free Photoshop trial for a month from Adobe.

**Technique:**
It depends on the nature of the images and the quality of the outcome you want. The **proper way** is to make a selection by hand. There are a couple of ways you can do this, for example:

- Create a path and convert to selection or mask layer (not sure if this works in Pixlr)
- Create a selection with the lasso tool
- Create a mask layer and directly draw on it with a brush
- ...

The **quick and dirty fix** would be to create a selection with the 'magic wand tool'. For that the image needs to have a fairly plain background and decent contrast with the person. The edges will be rough tough, since created by an algorithm and not your superior eye. ;)

I think you should easily be able to find tutorials on any of these basic techniques online.